# Solr does not set searching to replicable

Tags: solr

I have a Solr 4.7 Instance with 2 Cores (`A`, `B`) and several Slaves that replicate from `B`. Also `B` replicates from `A`.

- `A` is `replicateAfter=optimize`
- `B` is `replicateAfter=commit`

That way, when I made a big update at night with optimize I just send the documents to `A`, got optimized and replicated through `B` to the slaves.

Daily at noon there was a small update, which was sent to `B` and then to `A` (without optimize). The trick was, that `B` immediatly replicated it to the slaves and afterwards `A` and `B` had the same index version, so it did not replicate again.

After a sloppy config update one vital setting might be lost, because when i do the daily small update the versions seen from `B` behave like:

Before indexation:

```
Master (Searching)  1000
Master (Replicable) 1000
Slave  (Searching)  1000
```

Just after indexation:

```
Master (Searching)  1001
Master (Replicable) 1000
Slave  (Searching)  1001
```

See that `Searching > Replicable`. A `commit` was sent but it did not show as `Replicable`. Nevertheless `B` replicated to the slaves.

Of course after a few minutes it was like this:

```
Master (Searching)  1001
Master (Replicable) 1000
Slave  (Searching)  1000
```

So `B` changed to the old state and replicated to the slaves. The update was lost.

### Now my question is, how do I upgrade `Searching` to `Replicable`?

Because in the previous configuration, the state after indexation was:

```
Master (Searching)  1001
Master (Replicable) 1001
Slave  (Searching)  1001
```

Which was fine.

Comment: What's the reason behind not sending everything to A and using replicate after both commit and optimize? You're sending everything to A anyway, and the reason why it work previously was because you got the same index version - and by luck that it meant the same thing. If suddenly a document got added to A for some reason, everything would break down until the optimize..

Comment: @MatsLindh, as a workaround all is sent to A with with replicate after both, like you suggested. The only problem is, I get 2 replications for the big update, one after the commit and 1 hour later after the optimize.
Your last scenario is theoretically possible, but in practice everybody used the default workflow which was described in the question.